# Replace multiple asterisks (***) DataFrame Python

Tags: python, replace

I need to replace in a dataframe the text: 
J***ge by Jorge, I have tried many solutions but I always get this error

> /usr/lib/python3.7/sre_parse.py in _parse(source, state, verbose,
> nested, first)
> 646             if item[0][0] in _REPEATCODES:
> 647                 raise source.error("multiple repeat",
> --> 648                                    source.tell() - here + len(this))
> 649             if item[0][0] is SUBPATTERN:
> 650                 group, add_flags, del_flags, p = item[0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLaPQ.png)
>
> error: multiple repeat at position 2

This is a summary of the DataFrame 
It's like 5000 records

```
import pandas as pd

colors = {'first_name':  ['J***ge','Luis','Peter','Doug'],
          'second_name': ['Chavez','Ma**ani','Jhons','Leake']
         }

df = pd.DataFrame(colors, columns= ['first_name','second_name'])

print (df)
```

[DataFrame Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLaPQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Clean the data before importing to pandas data frame. Use [dictionary comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) to modify the dictionary, and use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to modify the list inside each dictionary item. Use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub) to replace the asterisks.

Note that `*` has a special meaning in regular expressions. It is a modifier that says: repeat the previous character 0 or more times. Therefore, it needs to be escaped like so: `\*`, or put inside a character class like so: `[*]`, which is essentially a class that consists of a single element - the asterisk. And `[*]+` means an asterisk repeated 1 or more times.

```
import re
colors = {'first_name':  ['J***ge','Luis','Peter','Doug'],
          'second_name': ['Chavez','Ma**ani','Jhons','Leake']
         }
colors = {k: [re.sub(r'[*]+', '', s) for s in lst] for k, lst in colors.items()}
print(colors)
# {'first_name': ['Jge', 'Luis', 'Peter', 'Doug'], 'second_name': ['Chavez', 'Maani', 'Jhons', 'Leake']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Timur
Edit your coe is:

```
import re
colors = {'first_name':  ['J***ge','Luis','Peter','Doug'],
          'second_name': ['Chavez','Ma**ani','Jhons','Leake']
         }
colors = {k: [re.sub(r'[***]+', 'or', s) for s in lst] for k, lst in colors.items()}

colors = pd.DataFrame(colors, columns = ['first_name','second_name'])
colors
```

But replace all *
Solve one datum, but not the others

The Name Ma**ani replace to Maorani, the correct is Mamani

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I already found the way to do it. First transform the data of the DataFrame to a list and then change them.
If someone finds a way with fewer lines, please let me know.

```
#The source DataFrame
import pandas as pd

colors = {'first_name':  ['J***ge','Luis','Peter','Doug'],
          'second_name': ['Chavez','Ma**ani','Jhons','Leake']
         }

df = pd.DataFrame(colors, columns= ['first_name','second_name'])

print (df)
print(df.columns)

# Replacing the manifolds ***
# clean the database. // Select the column
df1 = df[['first_name']]

df_up = df1['first_name'].tolist() #convert column to list
s = str(df_up) # the list to string
new_s = s.replace('J***ge','Jorge') # replacing
output = eval(new_s) # replacing
output = pd.DataFrame(output, columns = ['first_name_rem']) # the list replaced to Dataframe
output = pd.concat([df, output], axis=1) #Concatenate the DataFrame
print(output)
```